# How to enable the save button automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable this save button automatically only when user checks the checkbox and write some text in the input field. I don't know what am I missing here or if there is any alternative method to do the same.

```js
jQuery("input[type='text']").on("keyup", function () {
  validate();
});

function validate(){
  jQuery("input[type='text']").each(function(){

    if (jQuery(this).val() != "" )
    {
      if((jQuery("#groupidtext").val() !="") && (jQuery(".cate").is(':checked')))
      {

        jQuery("#save_me").removeAttr("disabled"); 
      }
      else {
        jQuery("#save_me").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    } 
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="groupidtext" type="text" maxlength="50" />
<input class="cate" type="checkbox"/><label for="1">One</label>
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="save_me" value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine you've just to listen also on the checkbox change :

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function () {
    validate();
});
```

**NOTE :** It's more efficient to use `input` event instead of `keyup` when you track the user change on `input`.

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").on("input", function () {
    validate();
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
jQuery("input[type='text']").on("input", function () {
  validate();
});

jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function () {
  validate();
});

function validate(){
  jQuery("input[type='text']").each(function(){

    if (jQuery(this).val() != "" )
    {
      if((jQuery("#groupidtext").val() !="") && (jQuery(".cate").is(':checked')))
      {

        jQuery("#save_me").removeAttr("disabled"); 
      }
      else {
        jQuery("#save_me").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    } 
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="groupidtext" type="text" maxlength="50" />
  <input class="cate" type="checkbox"/><label for="1">One</label>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="save_me" value="Save"/>

</form>
```